# Azure ADLS - To list Blobs getting OSError("(10054, \'WASECONNRESET\') using Python

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

I am getting Error: Unable to stream download

The container has a large size of files. Please let me know how to list blob names within a specified container.

SAS Token/URL has privileges : READ&LIST&WRITE
Please let me know if you want more information, Thanks.

Q1. Error: Unable to stream download

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient 

sas_url="https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]?[SAS_Token]"  
container=ContainerClient.from_container_url(sas_url) 
blob_list=container.list_blobs()
for blob in blob_list:
print(blob.name+'\n')
```

I want to list blobs in sub_folder='abc/def/ghi' under [container]. Thanks in advance.

Q2. I have tried with the SAS URL approach but getting an error: The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

def azure_connect_sas_url(source_container_sas_url, source_container_name):
    try:
        blob_source_service_client = BlobServiceClient(source_container_sas_url)
        source_container_client = blob_source_service_client.get_container_client(source_container_name)
        print ("SAS URL -- Connected.")
        return source_container_client

    except Exception as ex:
        print ("Error: " + str(ex))

def main():
    try:
        azure_sas_url = 'https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]?[SAS_Token]'
        container_name = 'abc/def/ghi'

        ## SAS URL
        connection_instance = azure_connect_sas_url(azure_sas_url, container_name)

        source_blob_list=connection_instance.list_blobs()
        
        for blob in source_blob_list:
           print (blob.name + '\n')
        
    except Exception as ex:
        print ('main | Error: ', ex)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

main |Error : The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.
ErrorCode: InvalidURi

Comment: You need to make sure that the URI *is* correct and it actually points to the specific resource.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying different options but still getting errors.
Please suggest to me how to avoid OSError for Q1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are confusing virtual directory path with container name. The container name is already included in your SAS URL.

You would simply create an instance of [`ContainerClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python) using that SAS URL using [`from_container_url`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-containerclient-from-container-url) method. The directory path ('abc/def/ghi') should be passed as a parameter to the [`list_blobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-containerclient-list-blobs) method.

```
azure_sas_url = 'https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]?[SAS_Token]'
container_client = ContainerClient.from_container_url(azure_sas_url)
source_blob_list = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with='abc/def/ghi')
for blob in source_blob_list:
  print (blob.name + '\n')
```

Comment: The code is working for the small size of containers. But getting error for large size container.
HttpResponseError: ('Connection broken:OSError("(100054,\'WASECONNRESET\')")',OSError("(100054,\'WASECONNRESET\')"))

Is it possible to fetch data in small chunks to avoid error and can we use dynamic container path inside using regular expressions:
source_blob_list = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with='abc/def/ghi/\d+/ijk/\d+')

Comment: Even though REST API supports this functionality, it is not exposed through Python SDK. You can raise an issue regarding this here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues.

Comment: Thanks, Gaurav for your reply and suggestions. I will raise it.
How to list blob names for large size of containers in batches. Could you please refer/suggest any document or sample program. That would be a great help.

Comment: You can use REST API directly or use SDK in other language like .Net or Node which supports pagination.